# Python, run package with `python3.6 -m somepackge.run`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'd like to do the same I can do with `python3.6 -m http.server`. I'd like to run my oneliner like that. How do I do this? For now I've got:

```
def run():
    print('Great!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I tried `python3.6 -m fastapi` and I've got `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6: No module named test.__main__; 'test' is a package and cannot be directly executed`,

and with `python3.6 -m fastapi.run` `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6: No module named test.run`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to define a magic file, called `__main__.py` within your module. See the [Python 3 docs on `__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html).

In there you typically run a single `main()` entrypoint function.

For examples, look at [pip's](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/__main__.py), or [Tox's one](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/blob/master/src/tox/__main__.py).